# Image upload => MERN Best Practices

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, image, file-upload

I'm creating a social media app using MERN stack. I need to handle profile pictures uploaded from users but I really don't know how to do it.

I looked up for it and there are tons of different methods, like converting image to **Base64**, using middlewares like **multer** or using **filesystem**, **formdata** or **cloud storage services** (this last one I'd leave since at the moment I don't have access to any cloud provider).

What are the **best practices** for this type of problem? What is the most recommended way to handle this in a way that is **fast and secure**?